# Batch file: Pause does not keep the window open

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made some batch files for builds etc, and some stay open until I press a key, some don't. Since the batch files are started on doubleclick from explorer, the last command always is pause.

This works:

```
@echo off
sencha app build testing
pause
```

This does not work:

```
@echo off
cscript /nologo newKey.vbs
sencha app build production
copy build\production\MyApp\app.js phonegap\www\
cd phonegap
cordova build android wp8
pause
```

Why does pause not wait for my keystroke here? Does it get any "keystroke" from the command before?

I am using Windows 8.1, if that matters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `cordova` is `cordova.cmd`, a batch file, and when a batch file invokes another batch file the execution flow is transferd to the called batch but does not return to the caller

You will need to use the `call` command, so the execution flow returns to the caller

```
call cordova build android wp8
```